# CarPlay's setRootTemplate fails to run completion handler or work using async/await

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

When using CarPlay's `setRootTemplate` method, I am unable to get either the completion handler *or* async/await to work properly. I need to perform some actions after the root template is loaded, but neither of these options allow for this.

This method is [documented here](http://CarPlay%20calls%20completion%20after%20it%20presents%20the%20template.%20The%20Boolean%20parameter%20is%20true%20when%20the%20presentation%20succeeds;%20otherwise,%20it%E2%80%99s%20false%20and%20CarPlay%20provides%20an%20error%20that%20describes%20the%20failure.%20CarPlay%20throws%20an%20exception%20if%20the%20presentation%20fails%20and%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20provide%20a%20closure.), saying:

> CarPlay calls completion after it presents the template. The Boolean parameter is true when the presentation succeeds; otherwise, it’s false and CarPlay provides an error that describes the failure. CarPlay throws an exception if the presentation fails and you don’t provide a closure.

**Example 1: Completion Handler**

```
interfaceController.setRootTemplate(tabBarTemplate, animated: false) { didSucceed, error in
    print("This completion handler never runs...")
}
```

Note: The above *does* work if you pass `nil` to the completion argument.

**Example 2: Async/await**

```
    do {
        print("This appears in console...")

        try await interfaceController.setRootTemplate(tabBarTemplate, animated: true)

        print("This doesn't...")
    } catch {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

The synchronous version of this method *does* work, but it throws a deprecation warning in iOS 15.

Is this a bug, or is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: Excellent question! I am not. I only have the entitlement allowing deployment using the previous CarPlay API and am waiting on Apple to approve the updated entitlement. Until that happens I am stuck working with the Simulator. Does this work differently with one versus the other?

Comment: The simulator has definitely been a big point of frustration with big differences in behavior compared to a real device (and sometimes even simulators from other minor Xcode releases :) that being said on my current Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100) the completion handler of `setRootTemplate` is called with a successful flag and a `nil` error. I set the template in the `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate`'s `templateApplicationScene(_:didConnect:)`

Comment: +1 Avoid doing any dev work on the sims. Other than basic setup you run into a lot of frustrating issues resolved on physical devices.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you had testing on a real device with a Carplay simulator. Were you have to fix the issue?

Comment: I found that you can only set a particular template instance as the root template *once* - I was trying to switch between two different templates deepening on state, but the second time I tried to set a particular template instance as the root it did not appear and there was no completion handler invocation. Using a fresh instance of the template each time worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/displaying_content_in_carplay) `setRootTemplate` has 3 parameters.

I found a wrong syntax in your code.

use `completion` argument as below

```swift
self.interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(listTemplate, animated: true, completion: { success, error in
  print("onCompletion")
  print(success)
  print(error)
})
```

hope it helps...